# Type inference on higher-kinded types

Tags: scala, generics

Trying to understand what "type" actually means in scala. 
Here is an example:

```
trait A[T]
trait B[T]

val typeTest = new A[Int] with B[String]

def test [F[_],T] (t:F[T],tt:T):T= tt

test(typeTest,5)   // line #1: compiles
test(typeTest,"5") // line #2: failed
```

`typeTest` is `A[Int]` an `B[String]` at the same time. Why line #1 compiles and #2 failed? Why `T` is inferred only for `Int`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to make this code compile is to provide a hint for compiler

```
test[B, String](typeTest,"5")
```

or

```
test(typeTest: B[String],"5")
```

It's funny that with the nightly build of Dotty vice versa

```
val typeTest = new A[Int] with B[String] {}
test(typeTest,"5")
```

compiles but

```
test(typeTest,5)
```

doesn't

```
[error] found:    Int(5)
[error] required: String
[error] 
[error]   test(typeTest,5)
[error]                 ^
[error] one error found
```

and one should provide a hint

```
test[A, Int](typeTest,5)
```

For comparison Scalac compile error was

```
Error:  type mismatch;
 found   : A[Int] with B[String]
 required: A[Any]
Note: Int <: Any (and A[Int] with B[String] <: A[Int]), but trait A is invariant in type T.
You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
  test(typeTest,"5")
```

The fact that currently Scalac and Dotty behaves (infer types) here differently means that (according to Scala specification) there is no deep difference betweeen `test(typeTest,5)` and `test(typeTest,"5")` cases. It's just imperfectness of type inference algorithms used by different compilers.

By the way, as follows from Scalac compile error message, one more option to help compilers to infer correct types is to make a trait covariant:

```
trait A[+T]
trait B[T]
val typeTest = new A[Int] with B[String]  
test(typeTest,5) 
test(typeTest,"5")
```

for Scalac and

```
trait A[+T]
trait B[+T]
val typeTest = new A[Int] with B[String] {}
test(typeTest,5)
test(typeTest,"5")
```

for Dotty.